# Unresolved reference kotlintest while using gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlintest

Here is my `build.gradle.kts` :

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.KotlinCompilerVersion

plugins {
    ...
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(27)

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        ...
    }

    sourceSets {
        getByName("main").java.srcDirs("src/main/java", "src/main/kotlin")
        getByName("test").java.srcDirs("src/test/java", "src/test/kotlin")
        getByName("androidTest").java.srcDirs("src/androidTest/java", "src/androidTest/kotlin")
    }

}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk7", KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION))
    implementation("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1")

    ...

    //Test
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.1")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.1")

    androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2")
    androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2")
    androidTestImplementation("android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1")

    testImplementation("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.1.10")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.8.7")
}
```

When building it with `./gradlew build` no error occurs but if I use the specified codefrom the doc :

```
val test by tasks.getting(Test::class) {
    useJUnitPlatform { }
}
```

I get the following error : `Task with name 'test' not found in project ':app'.`

My `settings.gradle.kts`:

```
include(":app")
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? It's weird AS can suggest me autocompletion and all but while compiling, I get this unresolved reference.

Comment: Are you trying to create custom task?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know much what I'm doing here, I newly converted to the gradle dsl. Maybe I should not initialize the test block like this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your issue is with this block,

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

> If you're not using **`test`** task then you can simply remove that
>   code and that error will be gone !

---

**Edit:**

If you want to use `test` task. try like this in project level **build.gradle**,

```
tasks.register("test", Test::class) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Don't I need to specify it in order to use classes from Kotlintest?

Comment: I try what you suggested in your edit. I get this error : `Cannot add task 'test' as a task with that name already exists.`

Comment: Have you removed your old one task?

Comment: Yes I did remove the previous `tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}`

Comment: check if it's already exists elsewhere, according to error stats

Comment: I did check and it exists nowhere. Ireverted my changes to kotlin DSL now. But I still have the error `Could not find method test() for arguments [build_2masodbfs0dkel3fd2gljcpis$_run_closure3@649f12a] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
` when I add `test {useJUnitPlatform()}` to my app gradle file